# How do I make all words in a list of words lowercase in python?

Tags: python, list, lowercase

I'm trying to make all entries in my list dictionary lowercase but I cant figure out a way to do this

```
def get_entire_word_list():
dictionary = []
f = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
for x in f:
    dictionary.append(x.strip('\n'))

f.close()

for x in dictionary:
    x.lower()

for x in dictionary:
    print(x)

return dictionary
```

This just won't do it :(

I tried

```
for x in dictionary:
    x = x.lower()
```

but that wont do it either.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Just call `lower` as you add the strings. `dictionary.append(x.strip('\n').lower())`.

Comment: `x = x.lower()` just re-assigns a local variable `x`, where the *new string* from `x.lower()` is assigned to. This does nothing to modify the list. To do this, you'd have to modify the list, or just create a new one. see the linked duplicate

Comment: @chepner AHH THANKS A LOT!! I tried that before but I put the .lower after the whole expression, like this: `dictionary.append(x.strip('\n')).lower()` That just threw an error

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of strings, called dictionary, you can use a list comprehension like

```py
dictionary = [x.lower() for x in dictionary]
```

to create a new list that contains only lowered cased string.

Comment: Without context, this isn't a useful answer. Just putting that line in there will do nothing except create a new list, and nothing in `dictionary` will be modified

Comment: I implemented `[x.lower() for x in dictionary]` but it doesnt work either

Comment: @qwertzniki6 you'd have to assign the result back to the variable `dictionary`